# Replace with regex in Golang

Tags: regex, string, go, replace

I've used regexp package to replace bellow text

```
{% macro products_list(products) %}
{% for product in products %}
productsList
{% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

I could not replace "products" without replace another words like "products_list" and Golang has no a func like **re.ReplaceAllStringSubmatch** to do replace with submatch (there's just FindAllStringSubmatch). I've used **re.ReplaceAllString** to replace "products" with .

```
{% macro ._list(.) %}
{% for product in . %}
.List
{% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

But I need this result:

```
{% macro products_list (.) %}
{% for product in . %}
productsList
{% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You can use capturing groups with alternations matching either string boundaries or a character not `_` (still using a word boundary):

```
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`(^|[^_])\bproducts\b([^_]|$)`)
s := re.ReplaceAllString(sample, `$1.$2`)
```

Here is the [Go demo](https://play.golang.org/p/4_KSyonY9y) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pL0uR0/1).

Notes on the pattern:

- `(^|[^_])` - match string start (`^`) or a character other than `_`
- `\bproducts\b` - a whole word "products"
- `([^_]|$)` - either a non-`_` or the end of string.

In the replacement pattern, we use backreferences to restore the characters captured with the parentheses (capturing groups).

Comment: Additional useful syntax for `ReplaceAllString` is `${1}.${2}`. This lets you replace something like `${1}0${2}`, which would otherwise run together using `$10$2` of the format above.