# Replace text in Go using regex

Tags: regex, go

I am working in Go, I have a text file in which I want to replace a text based on a regex, but it's not working as expected even when I already tested the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/sx0zks/3) and it says that there's a match.

I made the basic example in play ground and I am getting the same result. I have 3 text files with the same label (`//==start== and //==end==`), it works for the first one, but no for the second and third. What can be avoiding the regex to replace correctly the text?

https://play.golang.org/p/nZdHg5IfZ89

This is the code that I used, I pasted all the string because I want to be sure that it's not the one affecting me

```
package main

func main() {

    var re = regexp.MustCompile(Myregex)
    s := re.ReplaceAllLiteralString(originalString,"replaced")
    fmt.Println(s)

}

var Myregex = `\/\/==start==\n(.+\n)*\/\/==end==`

var originalString = `// @Author: someone
// @Date:   2018-01-23T16:46:09-04:00
// @Email:  dddddddd@gmail.com
// @Filename: _material.themes.scss
// @Last modified by:   Someone
// @Last modified time: 2018-01-23T18:40:39-04:00

@include angular-material-theme($theme);

.app-dark {
    @include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
}

.app-pink {
    @include angular-material-theme($pink-theme);
}

//==start==
//==end==`
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question body instead of linking to it.

Comment: @Adrian done! I added all the string due that I want to be sure that it's not the cause of the problem. Thanks

Comment: The text isn't the same as in the regex101 link, so the match doesn't exist in the Go example. You're also using pcre there rather than Go. You also probably need a multi-line flag.

Comment: @JimB my bad, I updated the content in regex101

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova: again the text isn't identical, so the match doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex with replace in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274282/regex-with-replace-in-golang)

Comment: @aerokite that is not the same. In the other post the problem with regex is that is replacing other texts that should not, and that is not my case

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova, did you check my answer?

Answer (score 11):

Hope this will help you

```
func main() {
    var re = regexp.MustCompile(Myregex)
    s := re.ReplaceAllString(originalString, "replaced")
    fmt.Println(s)
}

var Myregex = `//==start==\n.*\n//==end==`
```

See in action: https://play.golang.org/p/GITAdHOOQOg